# How to deal with “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error while adding large data set in hashMap

Tags: java, out-of-memory

While I'm trying to add a large number of data set into a collection, I'm getting OutOfHeapError.

I'm using `-Xmx1024M`.

`ArrayList` and `HashMap` both got the same issue.

Is there any way to store/cache partial results that would decrease the memory requirement for large operations?

I need to know whether a column in a table( could be from flatfile or DB) is unique after reading it in memory.

please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is but it depends on what the data contains (which you haven't said what it is) However I would just use more memory if you can. 1 GB isn't that much these days. 1 GB costs less than $10.

Comment: Explain more about your scenario. If you are just trying to see if all the values of a given column or unique within the table then you can as well achieve this with some SQL i believe....explain why you have to load it to memory?

Comment: I've to load ii into memory 'casue I can't go for SQL root( which would have plain and simple). And I've to perform some operation on the data set to figure out the weight of the column.

Answer (score 2):

Use ehcache ([ehcache](http://ehcache.org/)) it stores unused data to hard drive, or use Guava's cache ([guava-libraries.googlecode](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)) it controls cache relevance and expires unused records.